# ReactJS - Prevent initial animation of modal with react hooks

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, react-hooks

I built simple Modal component which will slide from bottom when opened. Animations are working fine when Modal trigger button clicked and backdrop clicked. But i am seeing slide-down animation at initial render of page. How can i prevent initial animation ?? I am specifically looking how to solve with react hooks.

Modal.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

import './Modal.css';

const Modal = ({ isOpen, onClose, children }) => {
  const modalEl = useRef(null);
  const handleCoverClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute('modal')) {
      onClose();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAnimationEnd = (event) => {
      if (!isOpen) {
        event.target.classList.remove('show');
        event.target.classList.add('hide');

      } else {
        event.target.classList.remove('hide');
        event.target.classList.add('show');
      }
    };
    modalEl.current.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);

    return () => modalEl.current.removeEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd);
  }, [isOpen]);

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div className={`ModalCover ${isOpen ? 'show' : 'hide'}`} onClick={handleCoverClick} modal="true"></div>
      <div className={`ModalContainer ${isOpen ? 'slide-up' : 'slide-down'}`} ref={modalEl}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </>,
  document.body);
};

export default Modal;
```

Modal.css

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.slide-up {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    animation: slide-up 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-down {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    animation: slide-down 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
    0% { transform: translateY(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(0%); }
}

@keyframes slide-down {
    0% { transform: translateY(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateY(100%); }
}

.ModalCover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.ModalContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 400px);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

demo (codesandbox) : https://codesandbox.io/s/l7x5p4k82m

Thanks!

Comment: Having read your example - you are really missing out on not using react-pose https://popmotion.io/pose/, it will save you having to write all the class logic and the animations and relying on css class names, just create a posed modal and change it via the useState hook. In terms of running your animation, just use an if statement inside the useEffect hook or inside the handle animation function, and don't run it after the first render by using your variables for the if statement or declare a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to do this with `classNames` since direct DOM access is discouraged with DOM. `modalEl.current` ref is assigned after initial render, it can be used as a flag that a component was mounted:

```
<div className={`
  ModalContainer
  ${isOpen ? 'slide-up' : 'slide-down'}
  ${!modalEl.current && 'hide'}
`} ref={modalEl}>
```

Applying `hide` class on component mount in `useEffect` may result in briefly shown modal animation.

Comment: Your example not working. You can test in codesandbox. i added codesandbox url

Comment: My bad. your example is working fine. but in my code there is setState happening immediately second time which showing animation. Thanks for the answer.