# open selected modal using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a code share on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53790963/reactjs-prevent-initial-animation-of-modal-with-react-hooks)

the code works just for one modal, I'm trying to add more than once but when I first click it opens all modals are trigger, then it works properly, that's the only issue that I'm facing

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const Modal = ({ isOpen, type, onClose, children }) => {
  const modalEl = useRef(null);
  const handleCoverClick = e => {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("modal")) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAnimationEnd = event => {
      if (isOpen.type === type && isOpen.modal) {
        if (!isOpen.modal) {
          event.target.classList.remove("show");
          event.target.classList.add("hide");
        } else {
          event.target.classList.remove("hide");
          event.target.classList.add("show");
        }
      }
    };
    modalEl.current.addEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);

    return () =>
      modalEl.current.removeEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);
  }, [isOpen]);

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div
        className={`ModalCover ${isOpen ? "show" : "hide"}`}
        onClick={handleCoverClick}
        modal="true"
      />
      <div
        className={`
            ModalContainer
            ${isOpen.type === type && isOpen.modal ? "slide-up" : "slide-down"}
            ${!modalEl.current && "hide"}
            `}
        ref={modalEl}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </>,
    document.body
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

**Style.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.slide-up {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  animation: slide-up 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-down {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  animation: slide-down 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-up {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

.ModalCover {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.ModalContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 400px);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

**Index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Modal from "./Modal";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
        <div>
          <h3>Coockie</h3>
          <p>content about coockies</p>
          <button
            aria-label="Close this popup"
            onClick={() => setIsOpen({ type: "coockie", modal: false })}
            className="closeBtn"
          >
            x
          </button>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}>
        <div>
          <h3>About us</h3>
          <p>content about us</p>
          <button
            aria-label="Close this popup"
            onClick={() => setIsOpen({ type: "about-us", modal: false })}
            className="closeBtn"
          >
            x
          </button>
        </div>
      </Modal>

      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen({ content: "coockie", modal: true })}>
        coockie modal
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen({ content: "about-us", modal: true })}>
        about us modal
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

- the live code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rwxm8mk38m)
- and this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2m5yz3rwl) has the code working with one modal

Answer (score 0):

Corrections:-

1) We don't want to render modal until `isOpen` is true

2) Correcting show and hide based on flag for `ModalContainer` instead of filling current value in reference i.e `modalEl.current`.

3) You are using the same state and update method for both modals. Create separate state and you should be good to go. Currently I have names `isOpen1` and `isOpen2` but you could give more meaningful name.

//index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Modal from "./Modal";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [isOpen1, setIsOpen1] = useState(false);
  const [isOpen2, setIsOpen2] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        {isOpen1 && (
          <Modal isOpen={isOpen1} onClose={() => setIsOpen1(false)}>
            <div>
              <h3>Coockie</h3>
              <p>content about coockies</p>
              <button
                aria-label="Close this popup"
                onClick={() => setIsOpen1(false)}
                className="closeBtn"
              >
                x
              </button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </>
      <>
        {isOpen2 && (
          <Modal isOpen={isOpen2} onClose={() => setIsOpen2(false)}>
            <div>
              <h3>About us</h3>
              <p>content about us</p>
              <button
                aria-label="Close this popup"
                onClick={() => setIsOpen2(false)}
                className="closeBtn"
              >
                x
              </button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </>

      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen1(true)}>coockie modal</button>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen2(true)}>about us modal</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// Modal.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const Modal = ({ isOpen, onClose, children }) => {
  const modalEl = useRef(null);
  const handleCoverClick = e => {
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("modal")) {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAnimationEnd = event => {
      if (!isOpen) {
        event.target.classList.remove("show");
        event.target.classList.add("hide");
      } else {
        event.target.classList.remove("hide");
        event.target.classList.add("show");
      }
    };
    const modalRef = modalEl.current;

    modalEl.current.addEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);

    return () =>
      modalRef.removeEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);
  }, [isOpen]);

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div
        className={`ModalCover ${isOpen ? "show" : "hide"}`}
        onClick={handleCoverClick}
        modal="true"
      />
      <div
        className={`
          ModalContainer
          ${isOpen ? "slide-up show" : "slide-down hide"}
        `}
        ref={modalEl}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </>,
    document.body
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply... I changed the code base on your logic which makes total sense... but still firing off both https://codesandbox.io/s/rwxm8mk38m ... think has something todo with the condition on the Modal.js `if (!isOpen) {`